# How can I convert std::make_unique<derived>() to std::unique_ptr<base>

Tags: c++, c++14, factory

I'm trying to build a factory method with self-registration based on (https://www.codetg.com/article/7r1QnR43bm3ZogBJ.html), which registers logic operations. But I can't figure out how to convert std::make_unique to std::make_unique. I'm always getting the same error:

```
return': cannot convert from 'std::unique_ptr<T1,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' to 'std::unique_ptr<LogicOperation,std::default_delete<_Ty>>
```

I'm still a noob on the subject of  unique pointer but I've read on cppreference.com

```
If T is a derived class of some base B, then std::unique_ptr<T> is implicitly convertible to std::unique_ptr<B>. 
The default deleter of the resulting std::unique_ptr<B> will use operator delete for B, 
leading to undefined behavior unless the destructor of B is virtual.
```

I have tried instead of making a lambda function,to use std::move() as shown in other examples on stackoverflow. But that does not same to work either.

main

```cpp
int main()
{
    Signal a;
    Signal b;
    a.setState(1);
    b.setState(0);
    std::unique_ptr<LogicOperation> logic = LogicOperationFactory::Create("AND");
    bool x[2] = { a.getState(), b.getState() };
    bool y = logic->operation(x, 2); // do and operation
}
```

LogicOperation.h

```cpp
class LogicOperation
{
public:
    LogicOperation() = default;
    virtual ~LogicOperation() = default;
public:
    virtual bool operation(bool*, uint8_t count) = 0;
};
```

LogicOperationFactory.h:

```cpp
        using TCreateMethod = std::function<std::unique_ptr<LogicOperation>()>;
    template<class T1>
    static bool Register(const std::string name)
    {
        std::map<std::string, TCreateMethod>::iterator it;
        it = s_methods.find(name);

        if (it != s_methods.end())
            return false;

        s_methods[name] = []() -> std::unique_ptr<LogicOperation> {
            // Constructs an object of type T and wraps it in a std::unique_ptr
            return std::make_unique<T1>(); // use default constructor
        };

        return true;
    }
```

LogicAndOperation.cpp

```
class LogicAndOperation :
    public virtual LogicOperation
{
public:
    LogicAndOperation() = default;
    virtual ~LogicAndOperation() = default;

    bool operation(bool* signals, uint8_t count) override;
private:
    static bool s_registered;
};

bool LogicAndOperation::s_registered =
LogicOperationFactory::Register<LogicAndOperation>("AND");
```

Can someone please explain to me, how I can make std::unique_ptr from a derived class (LogicAndOperation)?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In particular: does `LogicAndOperation` inherit publicly and unambiguously from `LogicOperation`?

Comment: For instance, [this compiles fine](https://godbolt.org/z/FLfPXY). But without a minimal and reproducible example, we can't really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the example code, I cannot see the issue.

This compiled and ran in C++14 mode (Clang 10). I filled-in some of the gaps that our example code was lacking. I cannot see your `LogicOperationFactory::Create()` function; is that where your issue is?

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

class LogicOperation
{
public:
    virtual ~LogicOperation() = default;
    virtual bool operation(bool*, uint8_t count) = 0;
};

using TCreateMethod = std::function<std::unique_ptr<LogicOperation>()>;

class LogicOperationFactory
{
    static std::map<std::string, TCreateMethod> s_methods;

public:
    template<class T>
    static bool Register(const std::string& name)
    {
        std::map<std::string, TCreateMethod>::iterator it;
        it = s_methods.find(name);

        if (it != s_methods.end())
            return false;

        s_methods[name] = []() -> std::unique_ptr<LogicOperation> {
            // Constructs an object of type T and wraps it in a std::unique_ptr
            return std::make_unique<T>(); // use default constructor
        };

        return true;
    }

    static std::unique_ptr<LogicOperation> Create(const std::string& name)
    {
        auto iter = s_methods.find(name);
        return (iter != s_methods.end()) ? (iter->second)() : nullptr;
    }
};

std::map<std::string, TCreateMethod> LogicOperationFactory::s_methods;

class FooLogic : public LogicOperation
{
public:
    bool operation(bool*, uint8_t) override {
        std::cout << "FooLogic::operation" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};

class BarLogic : public LogicOperation
{
public:
    bool operation(bool*, uint8_t) override {
        std::cout << "BarLogic::operation" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};

static bool s_registeredFooLogic = LogicOperationFactory::Register<FooLogic>("FooLogic");
static bool s_registeredBarLogic = LogicOperationFactory::Register<BarLogic>("BarLogic");

int main() {
    assert(s_registeredFooLogic && s_registeredBarLogic);
    auto bar_logic = LogicOperationFactory::Create("BarLogic");
    bool flag = false;
    bar_logic->operation(&flag, 1);

    auto null_logic = LogicOperationFactory::Create("ThisDoesNotExist");
    assert(nullptr == null_logic);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you've added more example code. Does your error stem from the Register function, or from the `LogicOperationFactory::Create` function? If it's the latter, I can't help you if I can't see it...

Comment: Added my own `LogicOperationFactory::Create` function .

Comment: Dear mciantyre, I've found the code that caused the error. I test your code and used it to check mine. I found out just now that an other piece of code took the wrong  template argument, which cause the error. Embarrassing mistake on my part. Thanks so much for the Help!